# How do I disable the three finger double tap to zoom gesture?

Tags: macbook-pro, zoom, gesture

On my macbook, when I double tap with three fingers, the screen zooms in (same as the accessibility zoom), and this type of zoom zooms in the entire screen. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three finger double tap to zoom is controlled in System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom > Advanced > Controls.  I suspect you have the "Use trackpad gesture to zoom" enabled.  Untick it!

[image]

Comment: You're correct, I looked at the regular trackpad settings.  I've deleted my answer.